# Upload with HTTP out of Java doesnt work when file includes "class"

Tags: java, eclipse, http, class

I'm trying to upload files via HTTP out of an Eclipse-PlugIn Client. When I use the getOutputStream of the HTTPrequest to add my files, the Connection fails for textfiles, that include the string "class". If "class" is not in the file, the connection works fine. I

don't have ANY idea why this happens. On the server side, the file will be uploaded, link shortened and can be opened. Everything works exactly how it should, except the text includes "class".

Comment: could you post the code where this happens?

Comment: Could be a firewall issue too.

Comment: You might want to include the error messages you get too.

Comment: thanks for your replies, I don't get an error message, the returncode of the HttpRequest is just 400... the code where it happens is just a simple http request whose body i fill with the multipart data, almost the same way in the first answer, except that i don't use StringBuilder, but the PrintWriter which should be redundant (i also use boundary etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use form-multipart encoded POST as in the example below:

```
    final String CHARSET = "ISO-8859-1";
    final String CRLF = "\r\n";
    String formFieldName = "uploadfile";
    String fileName = "upload.jpeg";
    String fileContentType = "image/jpeg";
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true); // if input is expected
    String boundary = "--------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    postData.append("--").append(boundary).append(CRLF);
    postData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(formFieldName).append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName).append("\"").append(CRLF);
    postData.append("Content-Type: ").append(fileContentType).append(CRLF);
    postData.append(CRLF).append(new String(bytes, CHARSET)).append(CRLF);
    postData.append("--").append(boundary).append("--").append(CRLF);   
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postData.length()));
    connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postData.length());
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), CHARSET);
    out.write(postData.toString());
    out.close();
    assert(connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    // if input is expected
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), CHARSET));
    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Cheers,
Max

Comment: thanks for your reply, i use a post request with form multipart almost exactly as you do, except that I use the PrintWriter and not StringBuilder, but that shouldn't make any difference?

Comment: HTTP 400 Bad Request
"The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

Comment: "almost exactly" may make a huge difference. check your code carefully. Can you give an example of your PrintWriter usage ?